how to create custom overlapped carousel slider in flutter?
I want to make a slider like the picture below:

I checked almost all pub.dev packages.
Especially packages overlapped_carousel and carousel_slider.
The problem with package overlapped_carousel is that it has bugs and does not work properly and is of very low quality.
The problem with package carousel_slider is that only three objects can be placed in it and it is not multiple, or at least I could not.
I am stuck in the mud, please help.
If there is a name other than carousel to find this type of slider, tell me so I can look for it thanks.

Try to use dynamic_carousel package...https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_carousel

Try out the following package: infinite_carousel
they display a screenshot of what can be produced:

